# There is a pending asynchronous operation, and only one asynchronous operation can be pending concurrently

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api2

When running this on my dev machine no issues, works great.  When deployed to my server I always get the error.

> System.IO.IOException: Error reading MIME multipart body part. --->
>   System.InvalidOperationException: There is a pending asynchronous
>   operation, and only one asynchronous operation can be pending
>   concurrently.   at
>   System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   offset, Int32 count, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

I am attempting to upload an image.  When I run this on my local machine no errors and the file does get uploaded.

```
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostFile(int TaskID)
    {
        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data. 
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        try
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // Holds the response body 
            string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            //// Read the form data and return an async task. 
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```

The error hits the last line of the code that begins with await.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"... and please: rework your format, and rework the title of the question!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance.  How is it now?

Comment: Is it possible that `PostFile` is being called a second time before the first read has completed? You should put a breakpoint there and check.

Comment: @DavidKauffman way better!

Comment: @JimMischel I am calling the postback one time.  I've tested it locally and runs great, when I put it on my Azure server that's when the error appears.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Needed to add the following line of code.

Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();

This was added just before the line that was erroring out.

So it now looks like this.

```
            var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            Request.Content.LoadIntoBufferAsync().Wait();

            //// Read the form data and return an async task. 
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
```